# Open cart multiple Quantities with different pricing

Tags: php, opencart, cart

I was wondering if there was an easy way on opencart(2.0.x) to let a user buy a product in 3 different Quantity options. 3,6, or 12 quantity, with each quantity having a unique price. (I.E- QTY 3 would sell for 10, QTY 6, 8.50, then 12 pack for 7). I tried to use the options module, to create a few radio button options but that tacks on the option to the original set price. I want the only options available to be the 3 types of quantity options. so if i choose the 3 QTY option I only pay $10.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

No modifications are needed for this.

Go to the product's edit page and look at the discounts tab. In here you can put different quantities and prices. Note that the price field is per item, so you just need to divide your total by the number of products.

You can leave the start and end dates empty if they aren't appropriate.

There is a demonstration of this functionality on the [official demo site](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42) and (I think) the dummy data provided when you first install OpenCart.